# Mysql command for showing a single column from two table (same named column in both table) with using two different condition

Tags: mysql, database

The database name is employee-information in that database I was trying to show one "person_name" column that is available in both tables "works" & "employee" by using two different conditions that will filter values in each table.
So that I can see the values filtered by the two conditions from both tables in one single "person_name" column.

**work & employee tables,**

[image: employee table data]

[image: work table data]

**Here is what I have done so far,**

```
USE employee_information;

SELECT employee.person_name, works.person_name 
FROM employee, works
WHERE city = "Miami" AND salary > 50000;
```

**The result I am getting,**

For that command I am getting this two-column from both table. Conditions are working but values are repetitive and there are two columns but I need to show one column filled with the value from both tables where those two conditions are true

[image: For that command I am getting this two-column from both table. Conditions are working but values are repetitive and there are two columns but I need to show one column filled with the value from both tables where those two conditions are true]

**My desired result is**,

```
person_name//table name
Alex      //values those are true by both condition in each table 
Robin Hood
```

Comment: You need a joining condition between the two tables. Your query creates a full cross product instead of linking related rows.

Comment: This would be more obvious if you used ANSI JOIN syntax.

Comment: Please add the desired result to the question.

Comment: I have added my desired result @Barmar 
Please have a look I have added the comment as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join the tables using `person_name` as the relationship.

```
SELECT employee.person_name
FROM employee 
JOIN works ON employee.person_name = works.person_name
WHERE employee.city = 'Miami' AND works.salary < 50000;
```

Comment: That's the error I am getting now,
#1054 - Unknown column 'works.city' in 'where clause'

Comment: Maybe by mistake, you have replaced the table name works with work but there should be an employee and in employee, there should be work.

I have changed that and it works now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

you must add a primary key in "employee table"  with name id
and a foreign key  in "work table"  with name employee_id

and your query will be

```
SELECT employee.person_name
FROM employee
WHERE employee.id, works.employee_id
and city = "Miami" AND salary > 50000;
```

Comment: You're missing the `FROM` clause, and `,` should be `=`.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can use `JOIN` , here is example

```
SELECT w.*,e.company_name,e.salary FROM works w INNER JOIN employee e ON e.person_name = w.person_name WHERE city = "Miami" AND salary > 50000;
```